# Report UI is broken in 4.6.2 and 4.6.3

Tags: civireport

We have version 4.6.2 and 4.6.3 installed in different sites, and just noticed that the new Reports tab interface UI is broken.  You can click on the tabs but the main body of the report settings - columns, grouping, sorting, filtering, etc - is always visible just as it was in older versions.

I've checked the official demo site, running 4.6.4, and it looks OK there.  I also have a dev site on my local machine running 4.6.1 and it's OK there too.  Seems unlikely to me that this was broken for 2 whole "dot" releases.  I've cleared caches on Civi and Drupal.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be the same issue as reported here: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35596.0.html

Could you check if you have the 'Extended reports' extension enabled? That isn't yet compatible with the new interface, so disabling it should fix the problem.

Comment: I certainly do.  In fact, I had upgraded it to the latest version before investigating this particular issue.  I'll check with Eileen as to it's status.

Comment: Glad to help. Eileen had commented in that forum thread, but I'm not sure if there's been any updates since.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have extensions/customizations/tpl overrides on your site that are interfering with the new report UI. Can you try disabling them?